# How to add authentication to ssh dynamic port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, authentication, encryption, ssh-tunnel, socks

I am using `ssh` client as a `SOCKS` server by running **on the remote server** this command:

```
ssh -f2qTnND *:1080 some-server-user@localhost
```

There is only one problem here: **anyone** can connect to the server and use it's internet connection.

Options:

- To use `iptables` to filter access to the **remote server**, but clients connect to the server from various non-statically allocated `IP` addresses so filters should be edited very frequently, which is awkward.
- To install a `SOCKS` server on the **remote server** (e.g. `Dante`). Ultimately this is the last option if there is no other simpler way to do it.
- Launching the command on **clients** instead of **remote server**. The problem here is that some clients don't run on `Linux` and it is awkward again to set up the tunnel (e.g. `Windows` + `Putty`). It is also more difficult for end users to set up their local `SOCKS` server (e.g. remembering the command, typing mistakes).

**Is there a way to add authentication to a `SOCKS` server made using `ssh` client?**

*Bonus question*: How to add encryption between the client and the server (made using `ssh` client)?

Comment: Wow. SSH to localhost to create an instant socks server ? not sure if this is brillant or insane.

Comment: I got the easy way by installing `dante-server`... and then realized that a lot of clients don't support authentication :( I think I will ultimately go with a VPN solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that it's awkward to tunnel in Windows.  Try [Bitvise Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/download-area), it's pretty easy to use.

There is no user authentication available in the OpenSSH client's socks server.

> Bonus question: How to add encryption between the client and the server (made using SSH)?

SSH is encrypted already, and it's pointless for you since you're connecting to the localhost.  You're better off disabling the encryption for more speed.  There is no encryption for socks, if there is one, it's probably not going to work for most clients any ways.

Comment: Thank you! For the second question by `client` I meant some random remote application and by `server` the `ssh` `SOCKS` server. You answered my question in the second part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

SSH is your authentication

If you only want the localhost to access bind it,

ssh -D localhost:port user@host

This ensures that only local programs can access the port.
vs 
*:port
This is binding to both localhost and all your addresses.

If you want to reduce the login attempts on your ssh just change the default port and rate limit it with iptables,

I would also recommend setting up fail2ban http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Why add an extra level of auth on top? 
If your too lazy just setup ssh key pair and a short cut to putty with the required settings.

Comment: The idea is to use the computer as a server. There is no point in binding it to localhost because remote clients could not connect. There is no extra level. The user connects as himself on the same machine just for the `ssh` built-in dynamic port forwarding. Once the port forwarding is set up clients can connect to the server. I do this just because some networks block some ports or limit bandwidth to some websites. This does not answer my question: Is it possible to add authentication to a server created like this?

Comment: How many users are you wanting to use the service. Maybe this is what your looking for http://www.catonmat.net/blog/linux-socks5-proxy/

You could use a dynamic dns service to over come the changing ip addresses. This does seem like a lot of work and extra complication.

Comment: You could bind external to a local port and have other local clients connect to you using ssh auth and forward through the same port. This is a little convoluted.